# Cant install a APK of an pre-installed app (Samsung galaxy a5)

Tags: apk

I'm trying to download a APK for Spotify premium but because of my phone service (fido) Spotify came pre-installed. When I install the APK it trys to update the pre-installed spotify even though it's disabled. How do I install the APK?

Comment: Depending on your provider - I don't know much about Fido - you may not be able to uninstall it. Can I ask why you need to install the app if it's already on your phone?

Comment: The Spotify APK is modified

Answer (score 1):

The best way is for you to uninstall the pre-installed Spotify first. You will likely need to "root" your phone. [This site](https://forum.xda-developers.com/samsung-a-series/general/how-to-root-galaxy-a5-a500fu-lollipop-5-t3137613) has some apps that you can use to root the Samsung A5.